# apache 2.4 howto "Require not ip" per virtualhost?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I know it's not efficient, but I have at the root htdocs (for "/") a big **.htaccess** whith banned IP inside, something like this:

```
<RequireAll>
Require not ip 1.163.1.5
Require not ip 1.163.192.83
Require not ip 1.163.193.136
... (4000+ IPs)
</RequireAll>
```

(it's scriptly updated upon analysis of the access log files: it scans for 404 w00tw00t and script kiddies attempts, see what I mean). The idea behind the use of a .htaccess is to be dynamically updated and parsed when I add new IPs :-)

Like many companies, I have a public Virtualhost Listen on http:80 with multiple ProxyPass rules, then multiple backend sites listening on localhost (or LAN IPs).

The goal is obviously to configure all the security stuff in the reverse proxies, like most company does. Hence, as expected, every request to the backends have 127.0.0.1 (or the local proxy IP) as source IP.

However I noticed this configuration is not working as expected: the .htaccess is evaluated for the backend sites **only**. Not for the front Virtualhosts. Excactly the reverse of what I need to do! :/

How should I do in order to make it work only for the Virtualhosts ? What is the best method ? Should I use RewriteCond instead ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it's impossible since RequireAll is for Directory tags.
Solution is :

```
  # BANNED IPs
  <IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap    hosts-deny  txt:/path/.htaccess.blacklist.ip.hosts.deny
    RewriteCond   ${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|NOT-FOUND} !=NOT-FOUND [OR]
    RewriteCond   ${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_HOST}|NOT-FOUND} !=NOT-FOUND
    RewriteRule   ^  -  [F]
  </IfModule>
```

With .htaccess.blacklist.ip.hosts.deny containing lines like this:

```
1.161.58.238 -
1.163.1.5 -
1.163.192.83 -
```